# Deleting the TLD from a variable

Tags: powershell, replace

So I posted a question earlier

Basically, I want to get from

```
google.com -> google 
stackoverflow.com -> stackoverflow
```

How do I do it?

Say I have two variables

```
$domain
$editeddomain

$editeddomain = $domain -replace >>> WHAT? <<<
```

Also it would need to delete the full TLD if it were a .co.uk etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if you're always just grabbing the first chunk (it's not www.) you could do `$domain.split('.')[0]` this would turn google.com into "google" and "com" ... and then grab "google"

Comment: TLD is the part after the last `.` co.uk is a second-level domain.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list of suffixes like this:

```
$suffixesToRemove = "com","co.uk","nl","al"
$regex = "\.($(($suffixesToRemove|ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))$"

$domain = google.com    
$editeddomain = $domain -replace $regex
```

Will get you:

```
PS> $editeddomain
google
```